# ASP.NET application restarting for no apparent reason

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms

I know this issue has been brought up a lot, but no matter what I try, it just doesn't seem to solve my issue.

My ASP.NET Web Forms application keeps restarting at what appears to be completely random time intervals, although they seem to normally range between 30 to 60 minutes. I most recently tried to run the application in ServerState instead of InProc, but this did nothing to solve the problem.

There does not seem to be any exceptions thrown, and neither the Error event nor the Shutdown event in Global.aspx are triggered when this happens. Instead, the Application_Start event is suddenly triggered and everything is reset to its initial state.

I read that changing certain files or changing files in critical directories would cause this to happen, but checking the modification date of each file when this occurs shows that not a single file in the application folder has been modified.

I have run the ANTS Memory Profiler to see if there are any memory leaks or other memory related issues that could lay ground to the issue, but memory usage seems completely stable, and never reaches any dramatic levels. At most the memory usage was at about 200 MB, where the CLR and ANTS itself stood for half of the usage. Either way, the issue seems to happen irregardless of the level of memory usage at the specific time.

I am deploying the application to a remote server. I do not have access to the server or any IIS configurations, so there is no way for me to actually adjust or monitor anything myself, although I can of course contact the people running the servers to help me do this. The restarts happen both when I run the application on my local IIS Express and on the remote server, but it does however seem to restart more often on the remote server.

I've added the contents of the Web.config file below. It's located in the root directory.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;url=~/VTT/Charts/;"/>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="100000"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBConnString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
      connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DBC;Connection Timeout=120;Integrated Security=true;Trusted_Connection=true;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=localhost:42424" cookieless="false" timeout="60"></sessionState>
    <compilation debug="true" optimizeCompilations="false" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="10240"/>
    <globalization culture="" uiCulture=""/>
    <authentication mode="Windows">
      <forms loginUrl="Default.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" name="adAuthCookie" timeout="60" path="/"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
    <pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting"
          assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="Default.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <caching>
      <profiles>
        <add extension=".ico" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
      </profiles>
    </caching>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST"
        path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

And the Web.Release.config transformation file. (I switched out the connection string parameters for obvious reasons; they are all in order.)

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBConnString"
      connectionString="Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=<cat>;User ID=<userid>;Password=<password>"
      xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" optimizeCompilations="true" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(debug,optimizeCompilations)" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Currently this issue is completely ruining my work, and my customer is extremely unhappy with constantly losing work due to application restarts. I'm at a complete loss on what to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: Side note: you should not store important info in web server application memory, so your customer should not "lose all work" because of application restart.

Comment: The application allows the user to input data in various ways (through tables etc.). The reason my customer loses work is because when they attempt to save the data, i.e. submit the form, the application restarts and their data is never actually saved to begin with. All data is obviously stored in a database, but the problem is that it doesn't always get there because of this issue.

Comment: So you mean customer submits form at the exact same time application restarts, and request fails?

Comment: Basically, the Application_Start event is triggered when the customer attempts to submit the form, or when a simple page request is made.

Comment: I can't quite work out how your authentication works, windows or forms as you have a child forms element of a parent with windows authentication set.    Anyway if its form authentication you don't have sliding expiry set so is it possible the auth token is expiring?  Or if windows auth then perhaps there is a setting to expire authentication after a certain amount of inactivity?

Comment: Are you still having trouble?  I might be able to help ...What access do you have to the Server?  Any Event Logs?  Can you request changes to IIS?